# Three-dimensional array initialization

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

In a bit of code I'm looking at, a 3D array has been initialized like so:

```
static const char codeset[6][256][10] = {
    [0] = { [0x20] = " ",
    [0x21] = "!",
    [0x22] = "&quot;",
    [0x23] = "#",
}};
```

(It does go on to initialize the rest of the cells, I've cut it short to show something readable.)

This does not compile. Is it supposed to? What's going on here?

Comment: Could we have the error message ?

Comment: syntax error : '[', pointing to the line with [0].

Comment: Compiles for me correctly (gcc 4.5.1). If you're on GCC, you can add `-std=c99` to your command line just to be on the safe side, as it's a C99 extension.

Comment: Alas, I'm in Visual studio, and apparently it's not going to work there: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34012666/-c99-array-initializer-in-vs2008.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use [C99 initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), but most likely your compiler isn't C99-compliant, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Good link, but unless my reading skills are bugged, it states that it's C99 extension, not GCC extension. GCC extends upon this by allowing to initialize ranges. +1 anyway as the link explains what's going on here. I didn't know that one too :)

Comment: @Kos Thanks, corrected. I was so much sure it is GCC-only so I didn't read thoughtfully.

Answer (score 3):

You are using C99 initializers, but your compiler does not support C99 or C99 is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, it trying to create the "alphabet" for xml string ASCII data. The " (double quote) character in xml is represented as &quot.  So the [0][0 - 255] group is xml.

It looks like an equivalence table. It translates from xml to ASCII or whatever.

Comment: Heh, maybe I was unclear - I know what the point of the array is, I want to know what's the problem with the initialization (Which, from what I've read, isn't actually supposed to work like that).